# SQL Server 2016 JSON Index

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

I have a table with thousands of rows that will only keep growing every day. One column has a JSON object that I need to run a lot of queries on. What is the best approach?

Here is a sample of one query:

```
SELECT
    PersonId,
    AccountNumber,
    JSON_VALUE(M.message, '$.PID.PID_5.PID_5_1') as FirstName,
    JSON_VALUE(M.message, '$.PID.PID_5.PID_5_2') as LastName,
    JSON_VALUE(M.message, '$.PID.PID_7.PID_7_1') as DOB,
    JSON_VALUE(M.message, '$.PID.PID_8.PID_8_1') as Gender,
    JSON_VALUE(M.message, '$.PV1.PV1_44.PV1_44_1') As ArrivalTs, 
    JSON_VALUE(M.message, '$.PV2.PV2_3.PV2_3_2') as Reason
FROM 
    dbo.Messages M
```

Is the best option to create an index for each column?

Example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_PersonView ON PersonView
(
    PersonId, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Gender, ArrivalTs, Reason
);
```

Or should I create separate indexes

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Person_FirstName
    ON Messages(FirstName)
```

I'm trying to build the fast possible query return, but currently this runs really slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **compound** index, it might be used ***only*** if the n left-most columns are used in the query (in the `WHERE` clause).

So your example will definitely ***NOT*** help if you have `WHERE DOB = ....` or `WHERE Gender = ....` or something like that - ***only*** if the n leftmost columns are used.

If you have queries that almost always restrict your result on `PersonId` and `FirstName` and `LastName` and possibly more - then that one compound index *might* help .... otherwise, smaller indexes might be the way to go (on columns that have a high selectivity, e.g. return a small number of rows for a given value - `Gender` is a typically *not highly selective* column, since either value male or female will return on average half the rows ---> will most likely never be used ....